# Customize Filters in Document Library

Tags: 2010, document-library, filter

We got several document libraries which has a column type. This like all other columns can be filtered by values that is inserted on the document library. In Type, we got file types like doc, docx, pdf, xls. xlsx and so on.

The users of the site use these filters often, but they have no clue if the document is saved as doc or docx and wish to combine those.

Can I make custom filter on document library where I for instance, combine doc and docx, xls and xlsx and so on?